# Add "Bearer-Token" to the http headers in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http-headers

I am trying to add a custom field 'Bearer-Token' in the http headers.
Adding the token as 'Authorization' : Bearer xyzqwerty works fine but adding 'Bearer-Token': xyzqwerty throws the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at HttpHeaders.applyUpdate (http.js:334)
    at http.js:284
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at HttpHeaders.init (http.js:280)
    at HttpHeaders.forEach (http.js:378)
    at Observable._subscribe (http.js:2362)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:42)
    at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:28)
    at subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:9)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (mergeMap.js:59)
```

Below is the code for the Interceptor I am using:

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http'
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TokenInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private injector: Injector) { }
  intercept(req, next): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>{

    let authService = this.injector.get(AuthService)
    let tokenizedReq = req.clone(
      {
        headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'bearer ' + authService.getToken()),
      }
      
    )

    let tokenizedReq1 = tokenizedReq.clone(
      {
        headers: tokenizedReq.headers.set('Bearer-Token', authService.getToken())
      }
    )
    return next.handle(tokenizedReq1)
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you do that in two steps? Use setHeaders per https://angular.io/guide/http#setting-default-headers.

Comment: this still doesn't solve my problem mate.

Comment: Are you sure about AuthService.getToken() the return type and the execution ?

Comment: yes.
If I remove Bearer-Token from the code, it starts to work as normal.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
const tokenizedReq1 = req.clone({setHeaders: {'Bearer-Token': authService.getToken()}});
return next.handle(tokenizedReq1);
```

also if this does not work you can try this way:

```
    const tokenizedReq1 = req.clone({
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Bearer-Token':  authService.getToken(),
          'Authorization': `bearer ${authService.getToken()}`
        })
    });
```

Comment: Only thing I can suggest is that you check authService.getToken() returns string and that it is not asynchrony function, in any other case headers won't be set correctly.

Comment: getToken(){
    return localStorage.getItem('token')
  }

Here is the code for getToken, it returns token stored in local storage, so string.

Comment: I have edited the comment, try it another way. If that does not work, I am afraid I can't help you without a Stackbliz or any other snippet.

Comment: Hello Milan, thanks for the help but I got my back-end devs to accept 'Authorization'; bearer qwrtyuuio. So the problem is solved kinda. Don't need to send it now..

Comment: No problem @IshankJain, I am glad you solved it in the end